# How can I compute and put the frequency of random integers in a arr[]?

Tags: java, arrays, random, integer, frequency

Im trying to write a method to compute num random integers in the range [0....range) and put the frequency in arr[].

```
public static void doSingleTest(int[] arr, int num, int range){
    for (int i=1; i<=num; i++){
        int random = randomInteger(int a, int b);
        arr[random]++;
}
```

Comment: What are the problems you're facing with this approach?

Comment: "How can I compute and put the frequency of random integers in a arr[]?". To me, that's what it looks like your method is doing.. without seeing anything else, of course

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd like to initialize your array:

```
int[] arr = new int[range];
```

Then in your method:

```
public static void doSingleTest(int[] arr, int num, int range){
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++){
        int r= randomInteger(0, range);
        arr[r]++;
}
```